# Can I and should I create one or many views and controllesr for TPH inheritance hierarchy in ASP.NET-MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, inheritance, asp.net-mvc-5, tph

I've read plenty of articles about inheritance with Entity Framework(in ASP.NET-MVC context too), everybody writes about database's side of the problem, but nobody brings up view side of the problem.

We got model classes:

```
public class Person {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
public class Employee : Person {
    public int? Salary { get; set; }
}
```

and in the dbContext we hold:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> {

    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false) {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create() {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

**Additional Question**: Shoud I keep also `public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }` in dbContext?

Now if I click on Controllers directory right-click then Add Controller like this:

[image]

The outcome is getting the controller with Index,Details,Create,Delete,Edit actions for `Person` class.

All the `Persons` including those which are `Employees` will be shown on the `Index.cshtml` list. In the `Details.cshtml` view Employee's `Salary` will not be shown. In `Edit.cshtml` view Employee's `Salary` can't be edited(it is not visible). **Furthermore** `POST Edit` action cannot(can it?)  bind `Salary` depending did `Person` xor `Employee` was edited. This could've been predicted, it is kind of obvious, but how to solve this?

**Main question:**

Should I create one controller for each type `Person` and `Employee` or only one for them togheter?

Should I create one Details,Create,Delete,Edit view for each type or only one and somehow check inside those views what type of object I want to present/edit/create in view? If I suppose to have one controller how to solve bindings in `POST Edit` action method?

Als if there is going to be **one** Index page with list consisting both `Person`, `Employee` objects how to check in the view what type of object is in the list when navigating to right Details,Create,Delete,Edit views?

Examplatory solution which comes to my mind: Create two controllers `PersonController`, `EmployeeController` with all the views, besides `Index` view and action for `EmployeeController`. Then basing on type of object in the list in index.cshtml lead to different views.